# self managed gitlab : use'special' characters in config file?

Tags: gitlab, config

I've got a dockerized installation of gitlab on my server. Now I'm working on it's configuration and I want it to prefix emails with "[gitlab]".

So I entered "[gitlab]" in the config file, stored it and run reconfigure. However, it only prefixes "gitlab" without "[]".

Is there a way to force it sending the subject including the "[]"?

Comment: Which config file are you using? Can you provide the exact contents of the setting(s) you are using in a code block in your question?

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to prefix emails with "[gitlab]".
> Is there a way to force it sending the subject including the "[]"?

There is no setting in GitLab to prefix email subjects at all. There is only a *suffix* setting:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_subject_suffix'] = ''
```

This setting does allow the characters `[]`.

You can see [all available email configuration settings here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/blob/76a06da7e350f8695504fee3d5abd4409336613e/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template#L98-111).

Comment: Sorry, didn't receive a notification for answers...

Yes, that's the setting which I used. The [] still don't apear. :-(